# Moving Cylinder

Tags: javascript, function, key

How To make Cylinder move like ROUNDING Not rotating, I mean down in the code how can I change Rotation with another word ROUNDING.

Because cylinder moves different way with rotate, and I want the options which will change Rotation.

```js
var looper;
var degrees = 0;

function video(ss,sl) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(ss);
    if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else {
    elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    }
    looper = setTimeout('video(\''+ss+'\','+sl+')',sl);
    degrees++;
    if (degrees > 1000) {
        degrees = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("video01");
    }
```

Comment: Is not clear what kind of animation you want. I suppose you are looking for  something similar to flip, check this site: https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

Comment: i need something to rotate on horizontal way not vertical way